# Orient oneself towards something

Tags: meaning

I know that "be oriented towards something" is OK.

The system is oriented towards preventing a certain result.

But is it OK to use "Orient oneself towards something"

> **She doesn't orient herself towards advice her mother gives her.**
>
> **I orient myself towards how I feel when I start eating something new.**

How do they sound to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Orient oneself towards something" is fine.  It means turn to face a particular direction:

> I oriented myself towards the mountain and began to walk.

The examples using "Orient" are a little odd.  You "follow" advice;  I'm not sure what "orient oneself towards the advice" really means, but I guess it means "metaphorically turn in the direction indicated, but not actually follow the advice".  That is probably okay.

I have no idea what "orient myself towards how I feel when..."  is supposed to metaphorically mean.  I wouldn't use this.

Comment: It means to monitor your feelings, how you feel after eating new food. To pay attention to it.

Comment: Well, not really, "orient towards" doesn't mean "monitor".  I would not understand you if you said that.